# Django media file not found

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

Media file is not getting. The fields related to User model are working(eg. object.username, object.email) but field with ProfileImage is not working.

### urls.py

added the below codes.

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

### settings.py

configured like below.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

### profile_detail.html

these are html code.

{% extends 'base.html' %}

```
{% block main %}
{{object.email}}
{{request.user}}

<img src="{{object.profileimage.image.url}}">

{% endblock %}
```

### model.py

This model is connected with User model with OneToOne relationship.

```
def get_profile_upload_to(instance,filename):
    new_filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4,filename.split('.')[-1])
    return "profile/{}/{}".format(instance.user.id, new_filename)

class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_profile_upload_to)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

### views.py

codes related to view.

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'user/profile_detail.html'
```

### Error code at console

```
Not Found: /media/profile/1/function_uuid4_at_0x7fbf37ce42f0.jpeg
[18/Oct/2019 10:01:45] "GET /media/profile/1/function_uuid4_at_0x7fbf37ce42f0.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 3421
```

Comment: show your models also

Comment: @arjun model is added can please look at it now.The fields related to User model are working(eg. object.username, object.email) but field with ProfileImage is not working.

Comment: @arjun I have added complete model.py now. do yo need view.py?

Answer (score 1):

I have added below urlpatterns in apps/urls.py instead of main urls.py thats the reason it is anable to render the image to template.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error and doing this worked for me.

Add the following code to urls.py in the project folder:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Note: The changes must be made to the *project/urls.py* and not *app/urls.py***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).